# Looking for exercices to improve my reasoning skills about ordering relations ( between numbers in particular ).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, order-theory

I think I grasp what is an ordering relation in gerneral ( reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive relation). I also have heard about trichotomy law for real numbers: for all real $a$, $b$ , either $a<b$ OR $a=b$ OR $a>b$.

However I  noticed that my intuition is wery weak when it comes to reasoning about ordering relations in general, and in particular, with reasoning relations between numbers.

Does anyone know about a reference in which I could find exercices , in order to improve my ability to make valid inferences about this subjet matter?

Feel free to point a less than college level reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Introduction to Lattices and Order* by Davey and Priestley is quite good. The first chapter has some exercises that will help you improve your intuitions and reasoning. The same is also true of *Lattices and Ordered Algebraic Structures* by Blyth.

Answer (score 1):

Order relations on finite sets are relatively easy to imagine. Think of a a total order as a list starting with a largest element, a second largest element, a third largest element and so on. Note that these elements are unique, i.e. for any $x \in X$, there is at most one element directly below $x$ (if you consider the natural order on $\mathbb{N}$, the element directly below $n$ would be $n-1$). For partial orders, this need not neccessarily be true; an element could have several other elements directly below and several elements above it. For example, the $\subseteq$-relation is a partial order on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, and the element $A = \{3,5\}$ has infinitely many elements directly above it (for example, $\{3,5,6\}, \{3,5,4\}, \{3,5,99\}$ and so on).

Regardless of the other answers, proving the following propositions could help you understand the concept of order relations a little better:

- Prove that if $X$ is a finite set and $\leq$ is a total order on $X$, $X$ has a unique smallest element. Then, conclude that $X$ has a unique second smallest element, a unique third smallest element and so on. Lastly, conclude that $\leq$ is a total order on $X$ if and only if there is a bijection $f: X\rightarrow\{1,...,|X|\}$ such that $x \leq y \Leftrightarrow f(x) \leq f(y)$. (This basically shows that all total orders on finite sets behave like a list of natural numbers)
- Prove that if $\leq$ is a partial/total order, then so is $\geq$, defined by $x \geq y :\Leftrightarrow y \leq x$.
- Prove that if $\leq$ is a partial order and $x_1,...,x_n \in X$ such that $x_1 \leq x_2$, $x_2 \leq x_3$, ..., $x_{n-1} \leq x_n$, it follows that $x_1 \leq x_n$.
- Prove that if $\leq$ is a partial order, there can be no $n$ different elements $x_1,...,x_n \in X$ ($n \geq 2$) such that $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 ... \leq x_n \leq x_1$.
- [Hard] Prove that if $X$ is a finite set and $\leq$ is a reflexive and antisymmetric relation, $\leq$ is a partial order on $X$ if and only if the function $p: \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X), A \mapsto \{x \in A\;|\;\forall y \in A: y \leq x \implies y = x\}$ satisfies $p(A) \subseteq B \subseteq A \implies p(A) = p(B)$ for all sets $A,B \subseteq X$.